# Are there only two levels in languages, meaning and symbols?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, symbolic-logic

Say in my language I have a 'variable x', in my language the symbol x represents a (variable) number, so at a level of meaning it is an object, and at a level of symbols 'x' is simply a set of lines in my typeface, how is it that we can talk about 'the variable "x"'? At a level of meaning it is an unspecified number and as a symbol we simply have 'x' should it be the 'variable whose value is denoted by x' or is there some other level where we can call the variable 'x'?

Comment: According to some philosophers three: symbol, object, meaning.

Comment: As on your last question, @mauro pointed out that you should distinguish between meta language and object language. Here, you should distinguish between syntax and semantics, which further breaks into reference and content (arguably). Then, to answer your question, there is also the level of pragmatics

Comment: @Papuseme how would I explain the use of 'the variable x' which level is this on? Metalanguage? and does 'the variable x' really mean 'the variable whose value is denoted by x'? or in the 'metalanguage' does 'x' unambiguously refer to the variable?

Comment: Having said that, why this "obsession" with variables? Outside math no variables at all. In natural language we have pronouns that work like free var: their meaning is "specified" by context.

Comment: @user1007028 please look at the concept of "variable assignment", that is, a function from object language variables to a set. This will answer your questions

Comment: Both meaning and symbol can in turn be analyzed into a number of categories. It all depends on how deep you want to take the analysis.

Comment: In Jean Baudrillard's famous language of simulation and simulacra there're more levels than mere syntactic symbol as you mentioned variable and signified meaning IIRC, there's another critical level of symbolic semiotics...

Comment: @Papuseme that did indeed help.

Comment: See e.g. [Peirce’s Theory of Signs](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce-semiotics/): "I define a *sign* as anything which is so determined by something else, called its *object*, and so determines an effect upon a person, which effect I call its *interpretant*, that the later is thereby mediately determined by the former. (EP2, 478)" 1/2

Comment: "What we see here is Peirce’s basic claim that signs consist of three inter-related parts. For the sake of simplicity, we can think of the *sign* as the signifier, for example, a written word, an utterance, smoke as a sign for fire etc. The *object*, on the other hand, is best thought of as whatever is signified, for example, the object to which the written or uttered word attaches, or the fire signified by the smoke.  The *interpretant*, the most innovative and distinctive feature of Peirce’s account, is best thought of as the understanding that we have of the sign/object relation."  2/2

Comment: You mentioned lines in your typeface and that got me thinking. Off the cuff, there is the physical medium, atoms of ink on paper or light emitted from the screen. In some sense there is no meaning here, unremarkable as just another term in the equation of the universe. There's the recognition of "x" as a symbol, still essentially devoid of content, but parallel is the emotional content of abstract typographic style (see [Asemic writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asemic_writing), for e.g.). It seems there is layer after layer, as @DavidGudeman suggested.

Comment: @DanielMGessel, yes, that's the sort of thing I had in mind. There is also, for example the difference between occurrences and function. In a predicate like "(∀ x .p(x)->q(x)) and (∀ x .q(x)->r(x))" are there two x's or or six? It depends on exactly what sort of thing you are referring to: typographical occurrences or a functional part of the formula.

Comment: @DanielMGessel when we consider 'layer after layer' is it acceptable to refer to different 'layers' in the same way, 'the set of symbols 'word', "the word 'word' "etc etc

Comment: @user1007028 For clear communication, no - carefully defining your terms can be helpful, just for your own sake. Personally I try to be forgiving while exploring to discover a common vocabulary. Language for new ideas is messy (why do quarks have charm?) and I'm usually the first to declare it meaningless, especially in tech where it often seems like it's marketing (it's new!) or a lack of understanding (no, it's old). Finding the right language for an idea that already exists, if you don't know it exists, is hard but can be a relief if you discover it. Patience and precision are both useful.